# Python 3.5.2 variable Error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have installed python 3.5.2 but when i try to get the value from user it doesn't work it only shows the message but never get the value from user how can i solve this problem??

[image]

Comment: You should be using `input` not `print`

Answer (score 0):

Like @Moses said, you have to use the [input()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) function:

```
>>> d = input('Enter the num here: ')
Enter the num here: 222
>>> d
'222'
>>> int(d)
222
```

Comment: If this solution is correct, could you accept the answer please?